# Huawei Ascend G7 Stuck in Fastboot & Recovery

Tags: recovery-mode, fastboot, usb-debugging, huawei

A few days ago, I must have been pressing some buttons by accident and my phone entered `fastboot & recovery`. Restarting does nothing, it doesn't matter what combination of buttons I hold down. Every time, it starts up with the standard Huawei boot logo then a black screen comes up saying `boot image verify failed` and then it goes to another screen that says:

```
<br/><br/>
"FASTBOOT&RESCUE MODE<br/>
 Please Connect USB Cable to your Computer and Open Hisuite<br/>
PHONE locked"<br/><br/>
```

I've tried connecting to Hisuite, but my PC doesn't register that my phone is connected. It does charge the phone, though, so not a problem with the cable/USB port. I suppose I didn't have USB debugging enabled? Can you enable it from PC? 
`<br/>`My phone isn't rooted, by the way. Also, you can't remove the battery from this phone without messing around with hot air guns, etc.

I've tried letting the battery run dead and then charging it again and restarting the phone, but nothing different happens`.<br/>`
I don't know much about phones, really, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Data on the phone are corruption. You need to flash the phone. Download the firmware